# Sidebar list with cakephp

Tags: ajax, pagination, cakephp-2.0

I want to make a sidebar list so when the user click on the item all the information that related to this item is viewed in a specific area in the same page , and its the same for all items,what is the best way to do that ( AJAX pagination or normal JQuery ) or there is another way to do that?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do that is using Extending Views it allows you to warp one view to another .Combining this with view blocks gives you a
powerful way to keep your views DRY.

for more details visit those links :

**Extending Views :** http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#extending-views

**Using View Blocks:** http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#using-view-blocks